# Getting crash when converting Error to NSEroor (_swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nserror

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x19db65dd4 _swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError + 36
1                                 0x101005410 closure #2 in closure #1 in MCRegistrationViewController.requestForVerificationCode() + 229 (MCRegistrationViewController.swift:229)
2                                 0x10105e2d0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed NSURLSessionDataTask, @guaranteed Error) -> () + 4339360464 (<compiler-generated>:4339360464)
3                                 0x100f956f8 __68-[BoomAPIClient callSuccessBlock:failureBlock:forTask:withResponse:]_block_invoke + 522 (BoomAPIClient.m:522)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x19042d610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x19042e184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1903e01d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1906de3c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1906d93b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1906d88bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
10 GraphicsServices               0x19a543328 GSEventRunModal + 104
11 UIKitCore                      0x19476d6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
12                                0x100fba224 main + 5 (main.m:5)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x190563460 start + 4
```

I tried to convert the swift Error to Objective C NSError to but getting a crash while doing.

```
if let convertedError = error as NSError? {

}
```

Thanks
Nicky

Comment: Did you trying not casting, are you really sure it's an NSError and not an Error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson basically I need to get the userinfo dictionary from Error, in order to do I need to typecast the Error to NSError,

Error dont have the userinfo object

Comment: If `convertedError` is an `Error`, it should bridge to `NSError` without any problems. And it is an `Error`, because otherwise `bridgeErrorToNSError` wouldn't be called. There is something else malfunctioning, but without more context it's impossible to tell. Btw, why do you cast to an _optional_ `NSError`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Actually I am trying to extract the serialized response from failure block in AFNetworking,   

error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] 

but it works most of the time but sometimes it crashes and it's hard to reproduce

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yeah, I agree, Here is the scenario, I have network layer which is written in objective c(return NSError) and the same network function is called in another swift view controller(Completion block has Error ), Here I try to typecast Error to NSError . which throws bridgeErrorToNSError.

I tried the normal way to typecast without any optional but that too crashes

most of the time its works but some time its crashes and its hard to reproduce

Comment: Maybe some sort of memory issue (zombie or so). Did you enable the address/memory diagnostics settings in the scheme editor?

Comment: I don't think its memory issue, still now I can't reproduce this crash but crashlytics is reported @AndreasOetjen

Comment: You need to somehow reproduce this, if not, I bet that is a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

From Error to NSError it is trying to access the errorCode and errorDomain.

```
extension CustomError: LocalizedError {
public var errorDescription: String? {
    return "Some localized description"
}
}

extension CustomError: CustomNSError {
    public static var errorDomain: String {
        return "Some Domain Name"
    }
    public var errorCode: Int {
        return 204 //Should be your custom error code.
    }
}
```

Comment: if the error domain, error code is missing then it will show some error in the crash log.